# How to get inactive records in One2many/Many2many fields?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

Let's put an example with an *One2many*, which is clearer: imagine that a person can have several pets, but a pet can only have an owner:

```
class Pet(models.Model):
    _name='pet'

    owner_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='person',
        string='Owner',
    )
    active = fields.Boolean(
        string='Active',
        default=True,
    )

class Person(models.Model):
    _name='person'

    pet_ids = fields.One2many(
        comodel_name='pet',
        inverse_name='owner_id',
        string='Pets',
    )
```

Now you have a person (*Id: 1*) who has two pets (*Ids: 56, 57*), but one of them is inactive (*the one with Id: 57*). If you print `person.pet_ids`, Odoo returns `pet(56,)`. Inactive records are not included there. Is there any way to show them when printing `person.pets_ids`?

I did this so far:

```
pets = self.env['pet'].search([
    ('owner_id', '=', person.id),
    '|',
    ('active', '=', True),
    ('active', '=', False),
])
```

But I was wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass

```
{'active_test': False}
```

in the context. In your case:

```
pets = self.env['pet'].with_context(active_test=False).search([('owner_id', '=', person.id)])
```

Comment: Your solution also works with recordsets, so it's even simplier: `person.with_context({'active_test': False, }).pet_ids`. Thank you very much @phogl!